# Google Calendar API - PHP - Search for single event

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I want to search and output a single event from my calendar. The calendar event contains a unique string, say numbers "12345678" (= the variable "string"). How can I define this search in the following code?

```
<?php
require_once "../google-api/src/Google/autoload.php";
require_once "../google-api/src/Google/Client.php";
require_once "../google-api/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php";

if (isset($_GET['string']) {

$string = $_GET['id'];


$client_id = '[concealed]'; //client of the service account
$Email_address = '[concealed]'; //email id of the service account
$key_file_location = '../google-api/API_Project-[concealed].p12'; //private p12
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("API Project"); //name of the application
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
// seproate additional scopes with a comma
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
$creds = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
 $Email_address,
 array($scopes),
 $key
 );
$client->setAssertionCredentials($creds);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
 $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($creds);
}

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

$calendarId = '[concealed]'; // Replace this with your calendar ID

$optParams = array(
  'singleEvents' => TRUE,
);

try {
    $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
} catch( Exception $e ) {
    print_r( $e );
}

while(true) {
    try {
        foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
            $name = $event->getSummary();
        }
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        print_r( $e );
    }
    $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
    if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
        $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

}

else{
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for [events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

> q
>
> Free text search terms to find events that match these terms in any field, except for extended properties. Optional.

My php is a little rusty but I can guess it might be something like this

```
$optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken, 'q' => '12345678');
```

The you can try the try me at the bottom to debug it.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?q=hair&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: I have events in calendar as abc 1, abc 2 but if i want to search for a specific event when I pass q=abc it displays all abc events but If i pass q=abc 1 it gives empty. Any suggestions please?